# Building multiple flavours android app creates multiple apks

Tags: android, gradle, build

I want to create an application with two flavours one with less features and one with more. How can i do it

Let us suppose there is

A - application

Flavour1 - feature1, feature2
Flavour2 - feature1, feature2, feature3

How to release one apk
and how user will install the application from play store how the user will know which flavour is going to be installed

Answer (score 0):

[There is nice documentation from google.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)

**Multiple flavours**

You should declare the flavors in the buildfile

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {...}
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
            versionNameSuffix "-demo"
        }
        full {
            applicationIdSuffix ".full"
            versionNameSuffix "-full"
        }
    }
```

}

After build two apk files will be created. They have different application id so you can publish them as two different applications to the Play Store. For example one free and one paid.

**Features**

There can be more solutions but the simplest one is to use buildConfigField.

```
productFlavors {
   demo {
       applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
       versionNameSuffix "-demo"
       buildConfigField "boolean", "FEATURE_1", "true"
       buildConfigField "boolean", "FEATURE_2", "false"
       buildConfigField "boolean", "FEATURE_3", "false"
   }
   full {
       applicationIdSuffix ".full"
       versionNameSuffix "-full"
       buildConfigField "boolean", "FEATURE_1", "true"
       buildConfigField "boolean", "FEATURE_2", "true"
       buildConfigField "boolean", "FEATURE_3", "true"
   }
}
```

Then in java source code you can check if features are enabled:

```
if (BuildConfig.FEATURE_1) {
   //run feature
}
```

Some othe approaches are described in the documentation.